# How find column data with special character at end

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column called HouseInfo which contains both alphabets, number and special characters.

Column data format: `AANNNNX`

where A is alphabet character A-Z , N is number 0-9 and X can contain both alphabet, number and special character eg 'AB1234A', 'AC32158' or 'DK8954;' or 'DS5466:' or 'SK1245>'

I am trying to write a query that finds column that has only special character at the end only. I have tried something like this but in this case I have to pass all the special character into it.

```
select * from testtable where HouseInfo like '______[;,:,<,>,=]'
```

Is there any way to detect all special chacter other than number and alphabet character at end position only?

Answer (score 6):

What about this

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE HouseInfo NOT LIKE '%[a-z0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in two way either using Like or Not Like

Using Like :

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE HouseInfo LIKE '%[@#$%]'
```

here into square bracket you can specify which special characters you want to match, I have specified them as example

Using Not Like

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE HouseInfo NOT LIKE '%[a-z0-9]'
```

Comment: The first suggestion is identical to the asker's and the second one to the other answerer's. What is new here?